# Connecting Macbook to WiFi network breaks internet for everyone

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos, parallels-desktop

I have a 2015 Macbook pro, which I bought about 3 months ago.

Some days ago, when I was using it, and connected it to my house's wifi network, everyone's internet connection suddenly dropped (as in they couldn't load anything, but wifi was intact). It didn't just happen in my house, so it makes me think something is wrong with my Mac.

If it helps, it's running Sierra.

I found out that this has happened to other people: http://www.mac-forums.com/internet-networking-and-wireless/183185-macbook-airport-breaks-internet-connection-entire-network.html

But nothing there was helpful.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

IMPORTANT EDIT: I believe I've found the cause of the problem: I'm using the program Parallels to run ubuntu, ** and if the program is not on, I can't lose all my internet connection.**
I've uninstalled the program and now I'm on a bigger problem now: I still can't connect to internet and I can't reinstall the program... help pleas

Comment: "but nothing there was helpful."  Specifically did you try the suggestion in the next to last post of that thread?

Comment: @Tyson Deletting  those settings files? Yes, I tried that, and it didn't help.

Comment: Does your MacBook have a fixed IP address on the local network?

Comment: @Toby Allen No, it doesn't!

Comment: Please add your findings as an answer and your new question in a separate post. Thanks!

Comment: I have two macs, one MacBook Air 2017 with Catalina and one brand new Macbook Pro 2019 still on Mojave.  Waking one of them when the other one is already connected breaks wifi router everytime for all other devices. I am completely buffled.

Comment: same here. what did you do to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would backup all your important files, reformat the disk and reinstall the macOS unless you would have a better clue of what the problem is. It might be something as simple as a corrupted preferences file or as difficult as a faulty hardware component. If you try this approach and you find out that everything is working as it should then at least you can exclude any hardware problem.

Comment: I had the same issue on my 2019 MBP. Resetting SMC, NVRAM and wiping the whole disk clean and repartitioning it did not fix the issue. It seems that it all started with an SMC update in the latest Catalina update, so I hope Apple will fix the problem in a subsequent release.